# Using traditional join clause with the (+) operator

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I'm really stuck with a SQL question from the JustLee Database. NOT looking for anyone to do my homework but unfortunately I am stuck...

> Questions: Show all authors and books they have written. Include authors that haven't finished writing their books yet. Include author last name, author first name, isbn, and book title. Use traditional join clause with the (+) operator.

My best guess is:

```
select lname, fname, isbn, title
from author a, bookauthor ba, books b
where a.authorid(+) = ba.authorid
and ba.isbn(+) = b.isbn
order by 1,2,3,4;
```

But I get a column ambiguously defined error. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The ambiguous column is ISBN. Why do you need to SELECT it, anyway? That's just a code; what you really want is the title.

Comment: No offense, but you should really find a different tutorial. Someone suggesting to use the old, outdated and proprietary `(+)` outer join in 2017 (or 2016) shouldn't be trusted. And they should be forced to read the Oracle manual, because even Oracle recommends to stop using that syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You need to qualify the ambiguous column name in the `SELECT` list:

```
select lname, fname, b.isbn, title
from author a, bookauthor ba, books b
where a.authorid(+) = ba.authorid
and ba.isbn(+) = b.isbn
order by 1,2,3,4;
```

It's generally good practice to qualify ALL columns in the select if nothing else than to make it clear what table the column is coming from. I also suggest you switch to modern `JOIN` syntax, and to list the columns explicitly in the `ORDER` clause:

```
select a.lname, a.fname, b.isbn, b.title
from author a
LEFT JOIN bookauthor ba
ON a.authorid = ba.authorid
LEFT JOIN books b
and ba.isbn = b.isbn
order by a.lname, a.fname, b.isbn, b.title;
```

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot of sense! I now understand I have to distinguish which ISBN to select. Also, I haven't been taught about left join but I will read about it in the textbook.

Comment: Dear Sir, - the Oracle notation for "left outer join" has the (+) on the RIGHT side of the equality in the WHERE clause. And for the join between `bookauthor` and `book` there can be no possible reason to do a LEFT join.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, fixed.

Comment: It is "changed" but it is not "fixed". The join between AUTHOR and BOOKAUTHOR should be a "left" join; the error was in the first query, not in the second. The requirement was to show even those authors who currently don't have an entry in BOOKAUTHOR.

Answer (score 2):

If the data model is correct, then `authorid` should be primary key in `author` and foreign key in `bookauthor`. Similarly, `isbn` should be primary key in `books` and foreign key in `bookauthor`. You are querying primarily for authors, and - presumably - you may have authors who have not written any books, so it is possible that they would be in the `author` table but not in the `bookauthor` table (although I would question why they are in the `author` table to begin with). The problem statement says "they haven't finished writing their books", so let's go with that.

To get the authors who appear only in the `author` table but not in `bookauthor`, you need a `left outer join` between `author` and `bookauthor`. Using Oracle proprietary notation (the `(+)` notation), the `(+)` should be on the **right** side of the equality:

```
... from author a, bookauthor ba, books b
where a.authorid = ba.authorid(+)
  and ba.isbn    = b.isbn
```

Notice two things:

For a left join, the (+) is on the right. To remember it: the "outer" join creates "fictitious" rows for the `authorid` values that are present in the table on the left but are otherwise missing on the right. So you need to add these "made-up" or "imaginary" rows to the table on the right (not on the left). So the (+) is on the right.

For isbn an inner join should suffice - there should be no book in the `bookauthor` table that doesn't correspond to a book in the `books` table. (Certainly not if the tables have the proper foreign and primary key as discussed above.)

*Note*: I would be quite suspicious of a book that wants to force you to learn the old, deprecated (+) syntax (and more generally "join syntax through conditions in the WHERE clause" as opposed to the modern, preferred, ANSI standard syntax using the ON or USING clause).

Answer (score 0):

One or more of the columns you're selecting exist in multiple tables. You have to qualify them.

Looks like the `isbn` column exists in both the `books` and `bookauthor` table, so instead of selecting `isbn`, you should select `b.isbn` or `ba.isbn`.